# navigation menu breaks on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have this site: http://mttv.co.il/
While on IE8, chrom, safari & FF everything is ok. 
The navigation menu breaks on IE7.
The problem is related to the "current tab" that for some reason gets a huge width.
Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an explicit width or use inline-block and not float.